# Why removing data in Firebase removeValue() is not working?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want that when the user has already pressed downvote, the next time they pressed the the down vote button, they will be removed from the downvote dictionary.

[image]

```
Firebase.getDownvote(selectedPostTimeStamp: postItem.timeStamp) { (error, downvoteFinalDictionary) in
        let keyExists = downvoteFinalDictionary?[Current.user.userID!] != nil

        // if the current user exists in the downvote dictionary
        if keyExists {
            print("Current UID exist")
            // remove the current user from the downvote dictionary
            self.databaseRef.child("channels").child(Current.user.channel).child("posts").child("post").child(Current.user.userID!).removeValue()

        } else {
             // uid doesn't exist   
        }
```

I also tried this one :(

```
self.databaseRef.child("channels").child(Current.user.channel).child("posts").child("post").child(Current.user.userID!).removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, databaseReference) in
                print("\n\n\n DATA IS SUPPOSED TO BE GONE!!!!!")
            })
```

Comment: Can you show us your structure for `channels`?

Comment: @dstepan there you go, I just edited the picture that shows the "channels" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I skipped 2 child(s): postIdentifier and downvotes :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your structure doesn't match your Firebase query. Your structure is channels > channel > posts > post > date > userId. But the code you're attempting is channels > channel > posts > post > userId. Firebase can't find userId at that path, so nothing will happen.

Try the below code to get you closer:

```
self.databaseRef.child("channels")
                .child(Current.user.channel)
                .child("posts/post")
                .observeSingleEvent(type: .value, with: { (snapshot) in


        })
```

I'll edit this code later to get you further along, if necessary. I'm not at my Mac right now.